# ArcObject 10.1 Java : Raster Analysis

Tags: arcobjects, raster, java

I have been working with ArcObjects Java for a short time and have not been able to find a solution to the following problems:

**How to get the Raster object from a IRaster reference?**

```
IRaster raster = rasterDataset.createDefaultRaster()

Raster rs = (Raster)raster
```

This gives classcastexception:  *com.esri.arcgis.geodatabase.IRasterProxy cannot be cast to com.esri.arcgis.datasourcesraster.Raster*

I have been unable to find the documentation of IRasterProxy. Apparently it is deprecated!!

**How to over write pixel values of an existing raster and store it permanently?**

I am following [this example](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-java/concepts/engine/index.html#/How_to_create_a_raster_dataset/000100000546000000/) but to no avail. I can see the pixel array is altered but when I open the raster in ArcMap I see no change.

**How to get Raster Info?**

```
RasterDataset streamOrderRas = (RasterDataset)streamOrderRaster

Raster raster = new Raster()

raster.appendBands(streamOrderRas)

IRasterInfo rasterInfo = raster.getRasterInfo()
```

I get AutomationException: *No such interface supported, stacktrace shows it goes inside com.esri.arcgis.datasourcesraster.Raster.getRasterInfo()*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was able to solve the problems:

If you create a new raster dataset and write new pixels to it then you have to build the attribute table and compute statistics from the first pyramid level. Then it shows up properly in ArcMap.

Instead of getting the rasterInfo from the Raster object like I was doing, use the RasterDataset object.

Still have no idea about the casting problem.